# String to alert Window

Tags: jsp, servlets

Ok, servlet generates String object, for example, "foo". How can I hand off this string to an alert window in JSP file? And how can i handle this event?

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    char[] charArray = reverse(request.getParameter("charArray").toCharArray());
    String s = charArray.toString();
    request.setAttribute("plz", s);
}
```

In JSP file I have a submit button and text field named "charArray"

And this is doesnt work

```
type="submit" value="Send" onClick="alert(<%= request.getAttribute("plz") %>)"/>
```

Comment: use confirm() function instead of alert()

Comment: Now it returns null... wtf

Comment: search example in Google how to use confirm()

Comment: the problem is that request.getAttribute returns null

Answer (score 0):

Are you forwarding/redirecting the request to the JSP file correctly?

You can try using sessions also if it doesn't work.